# Is there scope of optimization in this neo4j query?

Tags: neo4j

What I have tried :-

```
UNWIND ["SVC_HAS_DCSV","APP_HAS_EPLD","DCSV_HAS_SVC_EP","PART_HAS_WGE","HAS_REMOTECONNECTION","EPLD_HAS_DCSV","PART_HAS_EPLD","EPLD_HAS_INSTANCE","EPLD_HAS_SVC_EP","ALLOW_CONN_FROM","DONE_BY_POLICY","LOCATION_HAS_DE","APP_HAS_SVC","DE_HAS_EPLD","DCSV_HAS_ENDPOINTS","ALLOW_CONN_TO","CLOUD_HAS_LOCATION","DE_HAS_WGE","DE_HAS_PART"] as rel_name 
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b) 
where r._edgeType=rel_name AND a.t_id="MCNM-TEST" 
WITH DISTINCT count(r) as r_count,rel_name 
RETURN rel_name, r_count
```

Here, I am trying to check for each relation ex. APP_HAS_EPLD, the number of edges in the graph when a.tenant_id is "ABCD-TEST" then collect each rel and r_count and return.

Comment: Can't you use some node labels to reduce the portion of the graph being traversed?

Comment: I guess no because it is x-crossing all set of nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can be optimized in its current form, since it's traversing the entire graph, without any index getting used. However, you can make certain modifications and try them.

1. Add a generic label to all nodes, say Entity, using the following query.

   ```
   MATCH (a)
   SET a:Entity
   ```
2. Create an index on the node label `Entity` and the property `t_id`.

   ```
   CREATE INDEX t_id_entity IF NOT EXISTS FOR (n:Entity) ON (t_id)
   ```
3. Now, try the following query.

   ```
   MATCH (a:Entity{t_id: 'MCNM-TEST'})-[r]->(b) 
   UNWIND ["SVC_HAS_DCSV","APP_HAS_EPLD","DCSV_HAS_SVC_EP","PART_HAS_WGE","HAS_REMOTECONNECTION","EPLD_HAS_DCSV","PART_HAS_EPLD","EPLD_HAS_INSTANCE","EPLD_HAS_SVC_EP","ALLOW_CONN_FROM","DONE_BY_POLICY","LOCATION_HAS_DE","APP_HAS_SVC","DE_HAS_EPLD","DCSV_HAS_ENDPOINTS","ALLOW_CONN_TO","CLOUD_HAS_LOCATION","DE_HAS_WGE","DE_HAS_PART"] as rel_name 
   WITH a, b, r WHERE r._edgeType=rel_name 
   WITH DISTINCT count(r) as r_count,rel_name 
   RETURN rel_name, r_count
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my query

How can I add generic label "resource" to this query?
`CREATE (a:%v $props) RETURN id(a) as generated_id`

here, %v is differing resource to resource

Comment: You can do something like this: ```CREATE (a:%v:Resource $props) RETURN id(a) as generated_id```, or like this `CREATE (a:%v $props) SET a:Resource RETURN id(a) as generated_id`